# How to hide hiding secret keys in commits to bitbucket private repo?

Tags: python, git

I'm using python. Currently, I'm doing this. I have a file named `keys.py` where I store in my secret keys such as AWS_SECRET and etc.

Inside my `.gitignore` I have keys.py so that it doesn't get committed to bitbucket.

My `keys.py` looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

AWS_KEY = "1231231231"
AWS_SECRET = "23123123123"
PHONE_NUMBER = "12312312312"
```

Inside the python file that needs the keys, I do the following.

```
import keys

print keys.AWS_KEY
```

The problem I'm having now is that now that bitbucket supports pipelines, I am able to do the testing and stuff and deploy to server straight. However, since `keys.py` isn't in my repo, bitbucket fails to test the code.

There is environment variables settings in bitbucket. But that will require me to change my codebase to accept environment variables.

What should I do to use bitbucket pipelines? Should I change my code to use environment variables? Is there any better approaches?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import os

AWS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_KEY', 'XXXXXX')
AWS_SECRET = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET', 'YYYYYY')
PHONE_NUMBER = os.environ.get('PHONE_NUMBER', 'ZZZZZ')
```

But first you need set AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET, PHONE_NUMBER in the environment variables in [bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-in-bitbucket-pipelines-794502608.html)

Comment: so, inside `keys.py`, I'm going to have it right? And then load env to machine myself. Another question, how do i make sure my environ variables will always be on my machine even after reboot?

Comment: You can add it to the file .profile or .bashrc or your current shell profile file , see this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables

Comment: Thanks, I think there should be a better way than putting them in `bash_profile`

Comment: if you use virtualenv add it to end <virtual_env_name>/bin/activate file, 
thus always be available when using the virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

You should use environment variables. That is the norm. You will have to adapt your code for this change.

A simple fix may be to have your `keys.py` file look for the environment variables. You can retrieve environment variables as follows: `os.environ.get("VARIABLE_NAME")`

As an aside: depending on your use case, you may want to write your tests such that they don't depend on *actually* calling the services; such as by writing mock classes specifically for testing. This is normal practice, and it will speed up your tests as well. Of course, that's not always easy or practical. So maybe look into mocks and other testing techniques.

Comment: Also see my edit about testing. It may not be something you can do overnight, but it may be a step in the right direction. Something to consider. Cheers.

Comment: What do you use to load env to that machine? `bash_profile`? Any other ways?

Comment: See [this link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-in-bitbucket-pipelines-794502608.html) that was provided by @Hydex -- You probably want these to be **secured variables**!

Comment: What if I have two projects which use different AWS_KEY?